# Access denied for Puppeteersharp

Tags: c#

I am using puppeteersharp to converting HTML to image:

https://www.puppeteersharp.com/examples/index.html

This is the code:

```
       string outputFile = string.Empty;
        await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
        var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
        {
            Headless = true
        });
        var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
        await page.GoToAsync("http://www.google.com");
        await page.ScreenshotAsync(@"C:\Users\myname\Documents\puppeteertests");
```

I checked the folder seems full control but I am getting this error - O tried different folders as well.

```
 <ExceptionMessage>Access to the path 'C:\Users\myname\Documents\puppeteertests' is denied.</ExceptionMessage>
```

Comment: Try running the program with administrator rights or try storing not on C:\

Comment: @AlexLarionov I am running visual studio with admin right. Also tried D:\ still same error.

Answer (score 2):

You're only giving it a path, add a filename to your output call...

```
await page.ScreenshotAsync(@"C:\Users\myname\Documents\puppeteertests\somefilename.png");
```

Comment: Yes needed the fileName at the end, Thanks.